# Correcting color of soil and water using QGIS

Tags: qgis, rgb, soil, water

[image]

RGB single band image merged together result as shown in photo.

After I merged them, I found out the blue color part is actually soil, but show up in blue instead of brown or actual soil color.

How do I correct it?

Version: QGIS 2.18.25
Captured by Micasense red-edge mx.

Comment: QGIS 2.18 is a very old version and probably not in use anymore by the most people here. You should consider updating to a current version - right now  3.22 (or 3.16 Long Term Release).